# Why am I getting this java method related error?

Tags: java, string, methods, replace, char

Beginner here looking for simple, "dumbed down" responses, since I'm still getting used to methods and java in general.

In my program, I'm trying to remove a specific alphabetic character (e.g. charInput = 'f') previously inputted by the user in a previous method from a string of at least 4 characters (e.g. "foxes fancifully freeze in frozen food"), resulting in a new string (e.g. stringInput = "oxes anciully reeze in rozen ood"). To do so, I've searched around and so am trying replace 
(e.g. stringInput = stringInput.replace(charInput, "") ).

Unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

```
The method replace(char, char) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char, String).
```

I tried casting the character inputted by the user as a string to see if that would help, but it makes no difference.

Could someone explain what is going on here (very simply)? And also a possible solution to this error? Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Foothill {
    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char keyCharacter = getKeyCharacter();
        String theString = getString();
        maskCharacter(theString, keyCharacter);
        countKey(theString, keyCharacter);          
        removeCharacter(theString, keyCharacter);
    }

    // get keyCharacter
    public static char getKeyCharacter() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstPrompt, strKeyCharacter;
        char keyCharacter;

        do {
            firstPrompt = "Please enter a SINGLE character to act as key: ";
            System.out.print(firstPrompt);
            strKeyCharacter = input.nextLine();
            keyCharacter = strKeyCharacter.charAt(0);

            if (keyCharacter == 'a' || keyCharacter == 'b'
                    || keyCharacter == 'c' || keyCharacter == 'd'
                    || keyCharacter == 'e' || keyCharacter == 'f'
                    || keyCharacter == 'g' || keyCharacter == 'h'
                    || keyCharacter == 'i' || keyCharacter == 'j'
                    || keyCharacter == 'k' || keyCharacter == 'l'
                    || keyCharacter == 'm' || keyCharacter == 'n'
                    || keyCharacter == 'o' || keyCharacter == 'p'
                    || keyCharacter == 'q' || keyCharacter == 'r'
                    || keyCharacter == 's' || keyCharacter == 't'
                    || keyCharacter == 'u' || keyCharacter == 'v'
                    || keyCharacter == 'w' || keyCharacter == 'x'
                    || keyCharacter == 'y' || keyCharacter == 'z') {

                System.out.println("You entered: " + keyCharacter);
            }

        } while (keyCharacter != 'a' && keyCharacter != 'b'
                && keyCharacter != 'c' && keyCharacter != 'd'
                && keyCharacter != 'e' && keyCharacter != 'f'
                && keyCharacter != 'g' && keyCharacter != 'h'
                && keyCharacter != 'i' && keyCharacter != 'j'
                && keyCharacter != 'k' && keyCharacter != 'l'
                && keyCharacter != 'm' && keyCharacter != 'n'
                && keyCharacter != 'o' && keyCharacter != 'p'
                && keyCharacter != 'q' && keyCharacter != 'r'
                && keyCharacter != 's' && keyCharacter != 't'
                && keyCharacter != 'u' && keyCharacter != 'v'
                && keyCharacter != 'w' && keyCharacter != 'x'
                && keyCharacter != 'y' && keyCharacter != 'z');

        input.close();
        return keyCharacter;
    }

    // declare final = 4 to be constant
    public static final int minimumLength = 4;

    // get theString
    public static String getString() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String secondPrompt, theString;
        do {
            secondPrompt = "Please enter a phrase or sentence >= 4: ";
            System.out.print(secondPrompt);
            theString = input.next();
        } while (theString.length() < minimumLength || theString == null
                || theString.length() == 0);
        input.close();
        return theString;
    }
    // mask keyCharacter with $
    public static String maskCharacter(String theString, char keyCharacter) {
        theString = theString.replace(keyCharacter, '$');
        System.out.println("String with " + " '" + keyCharacter + "' " + " masked.");
        System.out.println(theString);
        return theString;
    }
    //count number of times keyCharacter occurs in theString
    public static void countKey(String theString, char keyCharacter) {
        int countChar = 0;
        for (int charTimes = 0; charTimes <theString.length(); charTimes++) {
            if (theString.charAt(charTimes) == keyCharacter) {
                countChar++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println( "It occurs " + countChar + " times.");
        return;    
    }
    // remove keyCharacter from theString
    public static void removeCharacter(String theString, char keyCharacter){
        //error line for below line            
        theString = theString.replace(keyCharacter, ""); 
        /*error line above: The method replace(char, char) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char, String)*/
        System.out.println("String with " + "'" + keyCharacter + "' removed:" +  '\n');
        System.out.println(theString)
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your `maskCharacter` and `countKey` methods? Your example is not compilable.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted them before posting because I didn't want to confuse people and I thought they were irrelevant. I'll edit my post to include them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the another simple solution. use theString.replace(String.valueOf(keyCharacter), ""); instead of theString.replace(keyCharacter, "");

**Explaination** 
In Java, a character enclosed in single quote is treated as character while a character enclosed in double quotes is a String and that's why you get compile error for replace().
There are two versions of replace.
one **replace(char oldChar, char newChar)** method can replace a character with given character.
second **replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)** method can replace a character sequence with given character sequence. Pls note that a 'String' is a character sequence

**replaceAll()** method replaces a string with given string where regular expression can be passed to match multiple strings in target

Comment: Placing a "valueOf" in my replace seems to have worked, as this completely removes the keyCharacter from the string, rather than replacing the keyCharacter with a space. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Kelsey ... would you like to up-vote my answer?

Comment: I did, unfortunately it says I need a reputation of at least 15 for it to be shown publicly. Sorry about that. :/

Answer (score 1):

```
theString.replace(keyCharacter, "");
```

should be

```
theString.replace(keyCharacter, ' ');
```

or you call

```
theString.replaceAll(""+keyCharacter, "");
```

But for the future: the problem is exactly pointed out in the error message:

`replace(char, char)`(you need 2 char parameters) `is not applicable for the arguments (char, String)` (you had a char and a String as Parameter --> you need to change the second parameter ... or use another method)

Comment: theString.replace(keyCharacter, '')  will not work. single quote is not a valid character.
also theString.replaceAll(keyCharacter, "");  will not work as the 'keyCharacter' is not a string.

Comment: thanks @griFlo .. would you like to vote for my answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void removeCharacter(String theString, char keyCharacter){
    //error line for below line            
    theString = theString.replace(keyCharacter, "");
```

because `keyCharacter` is a character and `""` denotes `string`. so write like this

```
 theString = theString.replaceAll(""+keyCharacter, ""); //going to replace all occurances of given string
```

or

```
 theString = theString.replace(""+keyCharacter, "");
```

or

use `space` between `'` like

```
  theString = theString.replace(keyCharacter,' ');
```

Other mistakes

`System.out.println(theString)` use semicolon here

`maskCharacter` and `countKey` methods?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple compile time errors I would list them  as:

1. `maskCharacter(theString, keyCharacter);` method is not yet defined
2. `countKey(theString, keyCharacter);` method is not yet defined
3. `System.out.println(theString)` you missed the `;` semicolon there
4. `theString.replace(keyCharacter, "");` which is because String.replace(char,String) method is not defined

> **key here is `""` means an empty string in java**, you should use `' '` as empty space character.

=========================

Agree with Rahuls suggestions

We should use `replace(String.valueOf(keyCharacter), "");` to avoid extra space being added with `theString.replace(keyCharacter, ' ');`.

Thanks for suggestion

Comment: with theString.replace(keyCharacter, ' '), using empty space character will result in extra space in your string.
the string "foxes fancifully freeze in frozen food" will result in " oxes  anci ully  reeze in  rozen  ood"
Notice the extra spaces..

So, wouldn't be a good idea to use replace(String.valueOf(keyCharacter), "")
which will return "oxes anciully reeze in rozen ood", which I believe as expected.

Comment: @RahulWinner: Yes, I just tried running my program after fixing it up a bit and I get spaces where I want the keyCharacter to be removed entirely.

Comment: @Kelsy:  simply using replace(String.valueOf(keyCharacter), "") would solve the issue without much hitch

Answer (score 0):

You want the `replace(String, String);` method. It allows you to replace a character with an empty String (i.e. remove a character or a string). The method `replace(char, char);` can't be used to supply an "empty" character.

`theString = theString.replace("f", "");`

Edit: don't use `replaceAll` if you don't need a regular expression.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` rather than `replaceAll`, so you don't have to worry about escaping regex special characters?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt How is it possible that I've never(?) come across this, even though it's been in `String` since 1.5. I've always used `replaceAll` instead, thinking the `replace` methods are for characters.

Comment: It took me a long time to find it too. I think its because of the confusing naming of these methods. `replaceAll` should have been called `replacePattern` or `replaceRegex`, since `replace` *also* replaces *all* occurrences.